# MySQL query LIKE returning even when not matching

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a query returning even the rows that do not match with the LIKE condition. My main goal is exclude the rows that do not contain "showOnlineStatus" in field params, that now are being actualy selected.

EDITED with the raw query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.id)
FROM users AS a
INNER JOIN session AS b
ON a.id = b.userid
INNER JOIN community_users AS c
ON a.id = c.userid
WHERE a.block = 0
AND c.params LIKE '%"showOnlineStatus":1%';
```

Any ideas why? Thanks for reading.

Comment: if this is a mysql question why do you have all that code which looks like PHP scattered about? And regardless of whatever language you use, this is not how you build a query. YOu should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Your `LIKE` clause appears to have a problem.  Maybe you should post the raw SQL query.

Comment: Edit your question and include the query *after* variable substitution.  Actually, the answer will probably be obvious when you just look at the query.

Comment: Thank you, edited with raw query now

Comment: `My main goal is exclude the rows that do not contain "showOnlineStatus" in field params, that now are being actualy selected.` If that's the case, use `NOT LIKE` instead of `LIKE`.